# Laravel 5.2 whereRaw with muliple where conditions

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

below is my query . i want to get all results If (nic or mobile) and course matches ,

please advice

```
        $conversations = Inquiries::whereRaw("( `course` = $request->input('course'))
            AND( `mobile` = $request->input('mobile') OR 'nic', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('nic').'%')")
            ->get();
```

Comment: Why are you doing whereRaw instead of properly taking advantage of there where functions?

Comment: @aynber 52 from using only where how can I get (nic OR mobile) AND  course this result ? pls advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly create a query, like this:

```
$conversations = Inquiries::where('course', '=', $request->input('course'))
    ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('mobile','=', $request->input('mobile'))
            ->orWhere('nic','LIKE','%'.$request->input('nic').'%');
    })
    ->get();
```